# mySQL incorrect logical statement, improper drop down

Tags: php, mysql

Attached is a picture that pretty much describes my entire problem:

Direct link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuaR0.png

I have a drop down table. Normally, it shows four entries, all the ones I want via this statement:

`$sql="SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, users.user_id, payments.fk FROM users, payments WHERE landlord = '0'";`

So everything works up until I change up the sql line a bit to this:

`$sql="SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, users.user_id, payments.fk FROM users, payments WHERE landlord = '0' AND payments.fk != 'users.user_id'";`

Basically, what I'm trying to select, is everyone that has the landlord flag set to 0 (which works fine in the previous code above), AND out of those people with the landlord flag set to 0, I want to only pick those people who aren't in the payments table. So basically, what should happen, is the drop down should only show three people.. Instead, just by adding that AND statement to my code, it now shows 4 people (4 times each for some reason), including the one person who is in the payments table.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? Sorry for the crappy explanation.

Comment: remove quotes around `'users.user_id'`

Comment: I've tried this with no luck. I've also tried replacing the != with <>, no luck.

Comment: Have you tried to use left join?

Comment: Without specifying the type of join, and the join criteria, your will get multiple results per `users` row.

Comment: I've tired both INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN but I haven't had luck. I've never used those commands before so I'm not sure if my syntax is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `LEFT JOIN`, and check if the `payment` field `IS NULL`

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, users.user_id, payments.fk 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN payments 
ON payments.fk = users.user_id
WHERE landlord = 0 AND payments.fk IS NULL
```

SQLFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46a88c/2

Comment: This works exactly, thank you so much! I'll have to study up on joining, thanks so much.

Comment: Here is a great blog article about joins, written by Jeff Atwood, the founder of StackOverflow - http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/